# 1С 8.3. Как правильно узнать текущего пользователя информационной базы на сервере?

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
ТекущийПользователь = ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.ТекущийПользователь();
ОрганизацияТекущегоПользователя = Справочники.Пользователи.НайтиПоНаименованию(ТекущийПользователь).Организация;
Сообщить(ОрганизацияТекущегоПользователя);
```

Код рабочий, но как правильнее сделать? Серверный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

если типовая конфигурация:

```
сообщить(ПараметрыСеанса.ТекущийПользователь);
```

Если у справочника пользователи есть реквизит ИдПользователяБазы :

```
Пользователь = Справочники.Пользователи.НайтиПоРеквизиту("ИдПользователяБазы",Строка(ПользователиИнформационнойБазы.ТекущийПользователь().УникальныйИдентификатор));
```